# kml global extent

Tags: google-maps, kml

I have a kml document that contains a polygon that should cover the whole world but it is rendered as a line along the antimeridian (i.e. the international date line) in Google Maps. Here is the offending snippet:

```xml
<Polygon>
    <outerBoundaryIs>
        <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-180.0,-90.0 -180.0,90.0 180.0,90.0 180.0,-90.0 -180.0,-90.0</coordinates>
        </LinearRing>
    </outerBoundaryIs>
</Polygon>
```

Workaround? Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Add some additional points (seems like it is going the short way, but wasn't quite that simple), this seems to work:

```
  <Placemark>
  <MultiGeometry>
    <Polygon>
      <outerBoundaryIs>
        <LinearRing>
          <coordinates>180.0,-85.0 180.0,0.0 180.0,85.0 90.0,85.0 0.0,85.0 0.0,0.0 0.0,-85.0 90.0,-85.0 180.0,-85.0</coordinates>
        </LinearRing>
      </outerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>
    <Polygon>
      <outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing>
          <coordinates>-180.0,-85.0 -90.0,-85.0 0.0,-85.0 0.0,0.0 0.0,85.0  -90.0,85.0 -180.0,85.0 -180.0,0.0 -180.0,-85.0</coordinates>
        </LinearRing>
      </outerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>
  </MultiGeometry>
</Placemark>
```

[not quite Working Example](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http%3a%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2FCoverWorldMG_kml.xml%3F0&hl=en&ll=-2.811371,132.1875&spn=132.694816,346.289063&sll=0,-45&sspn=132.74551,346.289063&t=h&z=2&iwloc=lyrftr%3akml%3acjy5Wd1IV6vbsEDb7g4q2m1n_MDcKmey4FV29MidhAg,g4dd84188512a233c,8.407168,121.939455)

Although it does seem to have issues at various zoom levels in both Google Maps and displaying it using KmlLayer in the [Google Maps API v3](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/CoverWorldMG_kml.xml).

[geoxml3 seems to work OK](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/CoverWorldMG_kml.xml)